# Creating functions in a loop with names depends on the iterable

Tags: python, algorithm, function, loops, automation

My goal : get the digit in the position i from a number x with a function called n`i`.

e.g : ( i = 3 , and x = 12345 ) => n3(12345) == 4.

My task surrounds a lot of number manipulation and I can have numbers up to 10**24.

I want to create 24 functions : n1 - n2 .. n24 at one go in a for loop like this :

```
for i in range(1,25):
    def n`i`(x):
        return int(str(x)[i])
```

In general, how can I automate the creation of functions from a list of data ?

I am still new to coding and your advices is much appreciated !

Comment: why u need different function if its objective is same

Comment: u can use new func to extract from `n3(12345)` to `i=3` and `x=12345`

Comment: I don't get what you want to say.

Comment: \you are new to coding. You might want to take Anurag Regmi's advice. Do you really need this? It might be better to re-examine why you thing generating so many similar functions and adding them to global is the way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just what you asked for.

```py
for i in range(1, 10):
    def fn(x):
        return int(str(x)[i])
    
    globals()[f"n{i}"] = fn  # update global variables dictionary

#use them like
n3(123456)
```

But I recommend defining a function that takes both arguments and using it

```py
def ni(i,x):
   return int(str(x)[i])

ni(3, 123456)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Though I want to avoid multiple arguments. The first solution is what suits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#example data
import random
ranges=25
n = 10**24
number = [random.randint(n,n*10) for x in range(ranges)]

def ni(x,i):
    return int(str(x)[i])

#print out all data and get the digit in the position i
for i in range(25):
    print(ni(number[i],i))

#print a data and get all digit
for i in range(25):
    print(ni(number[1],i))

#print a data and get the digit in the position i
ni(number[9],3)
ni(number[7],2)
ni(number[8],7)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I can't use functions with multiple arguments ^^

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following simple code to declare different function name (mesh name is my case) wrt different iteration number.

```
meshname="mesh_{}".format(It)
```

for which "It" represents the iteration number.