# Create a function in a loop with unique name and hard-coded coefficient

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am solving some physics problem with a time-dependent Hamiltonian. I need a coefficient function of the following form:

```
def coeff(t):
   return 0.3*np.exp(t)
```

Because of the solver that I use the coefficient function has to have that form and does not take additional arguments. The coefficient (the 0.3 in above example) comes from a nxn table. For 2x2 sized problems I simply wrote 4 coefficient functions coeff_00, coeff_01, coeff_10, coeff_11; but for larger problems this is tedious.

I tried to create functions in a loop following [Creating functions in a loop with names depends on the iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044114/creating-functions-in-a-loop-with-names-depends-on-the-iterable):

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    def fn(x):
        return int(str(x)[i])
    
    globals()[f"n{i}"] = fn  # update global variables dictionary
```

```
for i in range(4):
   for k in range(4):
       def fn(x):
          return A[i][k]*np.exp(x)
    
       globals()[f"n{i}{k}"] = fn  # update global variables dictionary
```

But I can't embed a "hard-coded" coefficient `A[i][k]`, since the function will be evaluated at call and not at definition.

Is there  a smarter way to do this? I know that ideally the function would be `fn(x, i, k)` but that would require a massive re-work of the solver and I hope it can be avoided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating functions (or lambdas) in a loop (or comprehension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-or-lambdas-in-a-loop-or-comprehension)

Comment: `Because of the solver that I use the coefficient function has to have that form and does not take additional arguments.` Can you get around that by using a `lambda t: coeff(t, *args)`?

Comment: Create a list (or dict) of functions, rather than injecting names into the global scope.

Answer (score -1):

> I know that ideally the function would be fn(x, i, k)

That's fine!

```
def fn(x, i, k):
    return A[i][k]*np.exp(x)
```

To turn that function into something with a "hard-coded" i and k, use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functools.html#functools.partial) (see [Partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)):

```
fnx = partial(fn, i=1, k=2)
```

Now `fnx` can be passed to your solver, and your solver can call it with just one argument.